# Subring and ideal structure of rings in the form $Z_n\oplus Z_m$

Tags: ring-theory

So I was wondering how the ideals and subrings of something like this look like. I know how the structure of $Z_n$ looks like since every subring of a cyclic group is an ideal. However, this is clearly not cyclic unless $n$ is relatively prime with $m$. Any help would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you prove that if R and S are rings with unity 1, then every ideal in R x S has the form I x J, where I is an ideal in R and where J is an ideal in S?

Comment: @CJD It is easy to prove the reverse case, every ideal in that form is, in fact, an ideal.

Comment: Here is an idea of how to prove the thing I said.  Let A in R x S denote an arbitrary ideal.  We want to show this ideal is of the form I x J.  Let (r,s) denote an element in A.  If you multiply by (1,0), you see that (r,0) is in A...

Comment: @CJD Got it! Thanks. Let $A$ be an ideal or $R\oplus S$. Then clearly the elements $(r,0)$ imply $I$ is an ideal of $R$ and $(0,r)$ imply $J$ is an ideal of $S$.